# Meteor: Single-Document Subscription

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, subscription

Whenever I encounter code snippets on the web, I see something like

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts', 'bob-smith');
```

The client can then display **all** posts of "bob-smith".

The subscription returns **several** documents.

What I need, in contrast, is a single-document subscription in order to show an article's body field. I would like to filter by (article) id:

```
Meteor.subscribe('articles', articleId);
```

But I got suspicious when I searched the web for similar examples: I cannot find even one single-document subscription example.

**What is the reason for that? Why does nobody use single-document subscriptions?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh but people do!

This is not against any best practice that I know of.

For example, [here](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/telescope-users/lib/server/publications.js) is a code sample from the github repository of [Telescope](http://www.telescopeapp.org/) where you can see a publication for retrieving a single user based on his or her id.

[Here](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/telescope-posts/lib/server/publications.js#L36) is another one for retrieving a single post, and [here](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/blob/master/packages/telescope-posts/lib/routes.js#L112) is the subscription for it.

It is actually sane to subscribe *only* to the data that you need at a given moment in your app. If you are writing a single post page, you *should* make a single post publication/subscription for it, such as:

```
Meteor.publish('singleArticle', function (articleId) {
  return Articles.find({_id: articleId});
});

// Then, from an iron-router route for example:
Meteor.subscribe('singleArticle', this.params.articleId);
```

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern that uses a single document subscription is a parameterized route, ex: `/posts/:_id` - you'll see these in many iron:router answers here.